# Is there a better way to validate multiple regex conditionals than giganic "or" statements?

Tags: regex

I am practicing regular expressions and to test myself, I was trying to make some sort of simplified password validation expression. Basically, it would accept `[0-9A-Za-z]`, but...

1) it needed to have a symbol (for simplicity sake, I only used `[#&@!&*%$]`)

2) it needed to have a capital letter

In my mind, the best way to do this was with positive lookahead statements. The only problem was the validation before and after the symbol. If I had the capital letter lookahead at the beginning, it would only validate if the capital letter came before the symbol, and the same for the end. The only way I could counter this was to make a massive OR statement with the entire thing copied, but one having the lookahead at the beginning, and one having it at the end. This is the monstrosity that I came up with:

```
/^[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*(?=[A-Z]+)[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*(?=[#&@!&*%$])[#&@!&*%$][A-Za-z|#&@!&*%$]*|[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*(?=[#&@!&*%$])[#&@!&*%$](?=[A-Z]+)[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*$/
```

I'll try to break it down into parts that make sense to me (and hopefully to you guys as well).

- **First part of the OR statement**

  - The beginning can be `[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*`, so that's what I start with
  - Then comes the first positive lookahead, ensuring that there is a capital [A-Z]
  - Then comes the second lookahead ensuring that one of the symbols in `[#&@!&*%$]` is present.
  - Then, it allows any of those necessary symbols to come next
  - The first part ends with another allowance of `[A-Za-z|#&@!&*%$]*`
- **Second part of the OR statement**
  The second part is much like the first. Well, almost an entire copy and paste. I put an `|` OR symbol in place, but then instead of having the `(?=[A-Z]+)` lookahead *before* the symbol, I check for it after.

All in all, I put in a good amount of effort into something that works (for the most part). I did some extensive Googling, but nothing really seemed to answer my question. Is there an easier way to go about what I am looking to do?

Comment: That is quite an expression!  If your environment permits, I would break it into multiple expressions - `/[A-Z]/` and `/[#&@!&*%$]/` should each be quick to test individually.

Comment: I doubt this works at all. So, you need to match a string that only has 0+ of `[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]` chars, should contain an uppercase letter and a special char from `[#&@!&*%$]` set anywhere inside? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gswowq/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to anchor the lookaheads at the start of the string (to just run them once) and add a `.*` or `.*?` before the required subpatterns in the lookaheads to allow the search anywhere on the line (note that `.` usually does not match line breaks, but your main pattern does not match them, so `.` is enough).

So, that said, you may use

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#&@!&*%$])[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*$
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - there must be an uppercase ASCII letter somewhere after any  0+ chars other than line breaks
- `(?=.*[#&@!&*%$])` - there must be a special char from the character class somewhere after any  0+ chars other than line breaks
- `[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*` - 0+ chars from the defined ranges or chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gswowq/1/). To make it more efficient, use the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast):

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^#&@!&*%$]*[#&@!&*%$])[0-9A-Za-z#&@!&*%$]*$
    ^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That really helps a lot. And I found the link about the principle of contrast to be very interesting. I would never have thought to use the negation of [A - Z] instead of the match any character symbol. I can see how could optimize it greatly.

Comment: Yeah, some would consider that a premature optimization, but the truth about a regex is that one cannot be too sure. I'd rather always follow best practices.